# Adding limitations and restrictions to my form submissions

Tags: html, forms, variables

I have a form to submit to my database and I need to setup restrictions on my form. Does anyone know how to limit certain links to be submitted on a form. For example, a user can only submit google.com links with anything following it, it just has to start with the root: google.com/(anything). Thanks! Below is some code of what I got now.

```
<input type="text"
    required pattern="google.com/ | apple.com/ | facebook.com/"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regular expression, something like that:

(....google.de/.*)|(....apple.com/.*)

"." stands for any character
"*" stands for repeating it any amount of times 
"|" is or, but you need to use brackets i think